# display of only one "li" among number of "li" tags having same class based on mouse function

Tags: css

Myself in the beginning stages of javascript want to achieve the following.Say I had some li tags which are further included with some li tags like this.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="" class="1"></a>
      <ul>
       <li class="2"></li>
       <li class="2"></li>
       <li class="2"></li>
       </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="" class="1"></a>
      <ul>
       <li class="2"></li>
       <li class="2"></li>
       <li class="2"></li>
       </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

*Now class 2 block is hidden originally in the page.My work is when someone hovers on a link of class 1 its respective block ( i.e., class 2) should display.But the code i had written is displaying all blocks having class 2
May be i can write a mouseover() function for each link of class 1,but is it correct?I had seen this type effect in some sites like linked in,awwwards.com*

Example link is
[Best Colorful Websites | Web Design Inspiration](http://www.awwwards.com/websites/colorful/)

In this link when mouse is hovered on a image,then for only on that image a symbol is display on corner bottomI want this type effect.

Can any please help me??Thanks in advance??

Comment: put some code on jsFiddle

Comment: can you tell me what is jsFiddle??

Comment: is an online testing environment... your example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dfv3P/1/ ... after this, anyone can update/fix it afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Well this can be achived with css only:

```
ul ul{
   display:none;
}

ul > li:hover ul{
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: i.e., all ul tags except the hovered one are hidden by this style rule. Isn't it?

Comment: at first, all ULs are hidden... the, on li hover, the ul inside the li hovered is displayed

Comment: But How if I want to apply some sliding on hovering??

Answer (score 0):

try a fast css solution (not tested because you did not put a jsFiffle code axample)

```
ul li:hover ul li.2
{
   display:block;
}
```

also, do not use only numbers in class names... will not work on some browsers
try `class="c2"` at least

Comment: class names are used just here

Comment: beased on your last comment, i updated the jsfiddle version http://jsfiddle.net/Dfv3P/2/

Comment: thanks you have given new learning source..Jsfiddle and also for the code.

Comment: i am glad i could help you... also you could thank me by voting my answer :)

Comment: I could that but my reputation obstructs me from doing that